# htaccess rewrite slash into get. does not read other get parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?c=$1
```

To get the same result as this

```
www.mydomain.com?c=name
```

when i call this

```
www.mydomain.com/name/
```

But then I can't add other GET parameter like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/name/?d=firstname
```

What do I have to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use QSA flag ie.:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?c=$1 [QSA]
```